# Rails 3, MySQL, tree structure

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, data-structures, nested-sets, tree-structure

I need to one of my project use a tree structure. I found [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) link and I tried it to use. My table structure looks this:

```
id    
user_id
parent_id
lft
rgt
```

When I try to create a root, so I will do this:

```
save_tree = TreeStruct.create!(:user_id => @user.id)
```

And then I try to add the childern:

```
  save_tree = TreeStruct.create!(:user_id => @user.id)
  save_tree.move_to_child_of(params[:parent])
```

But in this moment I am stil over and over again getting the error **Couldn't find TreeStruct with id=12**. The content of my DB table with the tree structure is here:

```
+----+---------+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | parent_id | lft  | rgt  | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      12 |      NULL |    1 |    2 | 2011-11-30 04:09:41 | 2011-11-30 04:09:41 |
+----+---------+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Could anyone help me, please, what I am still doing wrong? I can't find on the right way to use this gem... Why is there needed ID with the value 12? I though this is not needed...

Million times thanks for every help! I am struggling with this problem already second day and still can't find the main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recomment to use the "ancestry" gem -- it's excellent at supporting tree structures.  It stores the list of ancestors in a comma-separated string, which makes look-ups very efficient.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry